# Как изменять стрелки в input [type="number"]

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

```css
.dateInput-day,
.dateInput-month {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<form class="dateInput">
  <input type="number" class="dateInput-day">
  <input type="number" class="dateInput-month">
</form>
```

Имеется вот такой код, и мне нужно подправить дизайн стрелок вверх и вниз, если это возможно, конечно.

- Вынести кнопки за пределы поля, справа
- Стилизовать кнопки: закруглить края и изменить цвет

Надеюсь есть знающие, заранее спасибо.

Comment: По-моему, тут такая же лабуда, что и со [стилизацией тега select](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/670629/178509): здесь нужно хорошенько поизвращаться, а если браузер не поддерживает CSS3, то использовать JS.

Comment: Я конечно понимаю, что stackoverflow - самый авторитетный ресурс, но мне кажется такие вопросы проще в гугле вбивать типа "стилизация input number", там тоже можно найти ответы, например: https://toster.ru/q/350012

Comment: http://jqueryui.com/spinner/

Comment: 2 минуты поиска дали понять, что стилизовать на чистом css нельзя (по крайней мере кросс-браузерно)

Comment: Да, средствами CSS невозможно кроссбраузерно стилизовать input type="range", но на js/jquery можно в несколько строк написать свое решение

Comment: Жаль, я надеялся оформить на css чтобы не нагромождать код. Jquery UI не хочу грузить ради пары кнопок, но похоже, что придется. Может есть какая нибудь легковесная библиотека, которая сможет мне помочь?

Comment: не ищите, не найдете, это только посредством JS и css  и то самому писать стили и script,  это вопрос из раздела scroll, который можно посредством css менять только chrom движке, можно для opera и chrom... а вот mazilla уже не поддерживает, хотя читал, что и они собираются от этого отказаться...  так что только самому

Comment: @Dantessss, jQueryUI можно не целиком качать, он собирается. Библиотеки наверняка есть и даже специально для этого элемента думаю имеется. Да и самому такое написать в целом занятие не сложное.

Comment: @Dantessss как и говорил, можно написать решение на 20-25 строчек на js. Если интересует, могу оформить в ответе

Comment: Например вот https://jsfiddle.net/6sfy7jhq/

Comment: @Ched  было бы отлично)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Решение на jQuery:

```js
$('.number .number_controls > div').on('click', function() {
  var input = $(this).closest('.number').find('input'); // инпут
  var value = parseInt(input.val()) || 0; // получаем value инпута или 0
  if ($(this).hasClass('nc-minus')) {
    value = value - 1; // вычитаем из value 1
  }
  if ($(this).hasClass('nc-plus')) {
    value = value + 1; // прибавляем к value 1
  }
  input.val(value).change(); // выводим полученное value в инпут; триггер .change() - на случай, если на изменение этого инпута у вас уже объявлен еще какой-то обработчик
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

input::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
input::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}

input[type='number'] {
  -moz-appearance: textfield;
}

.number {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  padding-right: 30px;
}

.number input {
  height: 30px;
}

.number_controls {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  width: 30px;
}

.number_controls>div {
  width: 30px;
  height: 15px;
  line-height: 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
}

.number_controls>div:hover {
  background: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="number">
  <input type="number" />
  <div class="number_controls">
    <div class="nc-plus">+</div>
    <div class="nc-minus">-</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Чтобы избежать возможных "неприятностей" в виде некорректного отображения инпута в разных браузерах, можно вообще отказаться от `type="number"` и использовать обычный `type="text"`, предворительно добавив "запрет" на ввод любых символов, кроме цифр и знака минуса:

```js
$('.number input').on('input change paste', function() {
  $(this).val(this.value.replace(/[^0-9\-]/, '')); // запрещаем ввод любых символов, кроме цифр и знака минуса
});

$('.number .number_controls > div').on('click', function() {
  var input = $(this).closest('.number').find('input'); // инпут
  var value = parseInt(input.val()) || 0; // получаем value инпута или 0
  if ($(this).hasClass('nc-minus')) {
    value = value - 1; // вычитаем из value 1
  }
  if ($(this).hasClass('nc-plus')) {
    value = value + 1; // прибавляем к value 1
  }
  input.val(value).change(); // выводим полученное value в инпут; триггер .change() - на случай, если на изменение этого инпута у вас уже объявлен еще какой-то обработчик
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.number {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  padding-right: 30px;
}

.number input {
  height: 30px;
}

.number_controls {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  width: 30px;
}

.number_controls>div {
  width: 30px;
  height: 15px;
  line-height: 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
}

.number_controls>div:hover {
  background: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="number">
  <input type="text" />
  <div class="number_controls">
    <div class="nc-plus">+</div>
    <div class="nc-minus">-</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Вариант с возможностью "пересчитывать" `value`, не отжимая <kbd>ЛКМ</kbd>:

```js
$('.number input').on('input change paste', function() {
  $(this).val(this.value.replace(/[^0-9\-]/, '')); // запрещаем ввод любых символов, кроме цифр и знака минуса
});

$('.number').each(function() {
  var numb = $(this),
    controls = numb.find('.number_controls div'),
    input = numb.find('input'), // инпут    
    interval,
    timeout;
  controls.each(function() {
    var control = $(this);
    var pressed = false;
    control.on('mousedown', function() {
      timeout = setTimeout(function() {
        pressed = true;
      }, 51);
      var value = parseInt(input.val()) || 0;
      interval = setInterval(function() {
        if (pressed) {
          if (control.hasClass('nc-minus')) {
            value = changeValue(value, 'minus');
          } else if (control.hasClass('nc-plus')) {
            value = changeValue(value, 'plus');
          }
          input.val(value).change();
        }
      }, 50);
    });

    control.on('mouseup', function() {
      var value = parseInt(input.val()) || 0;
      if (control.hasClass('nc-minus')) {
        value = changeValue(value, 'minus');
      } else if (control.hasClass('nc-plus')) {
        value = changeValue(value, 'plus');
      }
      input.val(value).change();

      pressed = false;
      clearInterval(interval);
    });

    control.on('mouseout', function() {
      clearInterval(interval);
    });
  });

  function changeValue(val, type) {
    if (type == 'minus') {
      val = val - 1;
    } else if (type == 'plus') {
      val = val + 1;
    }
    return val;
  }

});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.number {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  padding-right: 30px;
}

.number input {
  height: 30px;
}

.number_controls {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  width: 30px;
}

.number_controls>div {
  width: 30px;
  height: 15px;
  line-height: 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
}

.number_controls>div:hover {
  background: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="number">
  <input type="text" />
  <div class="number_controls">
    <div class="nc-plus">+</div>
    <div class="nc-minus">-</div>
  </div>
</div>
<br /><br />
<div class="number">
  <input type="text" />
  <div class="number_controls">
    <div class="nc-plus">+</div>
    <div class="nc-minus">-</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: А можно ли сделать так, что бы при зажатии клавиши число будут увеличиваться пока не отпустить клавишу ?

Comment: @AlisherYerkimbekov можно. Дополнил ответ

Comment: У вас там баг. Если зажать и отвести мышку и отпустить за пределами кнопки плюс/минус, то она будет увеличиваться бесконечно.

Comment: @AlisherYerkimbekov поправил

Comment: И ещё, если вписать туда своё значение и нажать на плюс/минус, то она вернется к прежнему числу, не тому которому мы написали туда    <br> UPD: в последнем коде.

Comment: @AlisherYerkimbekov и это поправил)

Answer (score 2):

К сожалению средствами CSS нельзя оформить эти кнопки, но есть способы с помощью доп. библиотек, например PrimeFaces UI.

Как установить: https://www.primefaces.org/primeui/#setup

Компонент spinner: https://www.primefaces.org/primeui/#spinner

После подключения библиотек, компонент инициализируется в 2 строчки:

```
$('#default').puispinner();

<input id="default" type="text" />
```

P.S. Библиотека компонентов избавляет от писанины кучи кода с неизвестными багами

Comment: Спасибо, за ответ, это крутая библиотека, но тяжеловата плюс нужен jqUI который я не использую. Но для будущих проектов мне она подойдет

Answer (score 1):

К сожалению, средствами CSS стилизировать невозможно, но можно использовать JS.
Решение на чистом JS будет приблизительно такое:

```js
function input_val( dir, elid ) {
 console.log(dir + " " + elid)
 var inputEl = document.getElementById(elid)
  console.log(inputEl)
 var value = parseInt(inputEl.value, 10)
  if (isNaN(value))
   value = 0
   
 if (dir == "dec")
  value--
  else if (dir == "inc")
  value++
    
  inputEl.value = value
}
```

```css
#dateInput-day,
#dateInput-month {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20px;
}
button {
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<form class="dateInput">
  <input type="input" id="dateInput-day"> 
  <button type="button" onclick="input_val('dec','dateInput-day')">-</button>
  <button type="button" onclick="input_val('inc','dateInput-day')">+</button>
  <input type="input" id="dateInput-month">
  <button type="button" onclick="input_val('dec','dateInput-month')">-</button>
  <button type="button" onclick="input_val('inc','dateInput-month')">+</button>
</form>
```

Решение, конечно же, нужно будет подогнать под себя, но это вполне рабочий вариант.

Answer (score 0):

Сделал специальный плагин под это numberPlugin всё расписано на русском как подключать, применён уже не на одном реальном сайте 
Плагин для стилизации input type=number
сайт плагина https://number-plugin.ru
для подключения плагина добавьте в head

```
`<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="number_plugin/number_plugin.js" type="text/javascript"> </script>
<link href="number_plugin/number_plugin.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">`
```

Создайте элемент типа input type="number"

`<input type="number" class="numb" id="1" value="1">`

В файле с JavaScript

`$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.numb').number_plugin();
});`

Comment: Дополните пожалуйста примером из ссылки. Ответы содержащие только ссылку, обычно удаляются.